# App.Config connection string format

Tags: c#, sql, app-config

In my App.Config I have the following section:

```
<appSettings>

  <add key="dbConn" value="Server=myServer;Database=Database;Trusted_Connection=True;Connection Timeout=600" />

</appSettings>
```

I'm grabbing this line by doing the following:

```
static DbRepository repo = new DbRepository(new DbRepositoryConfig
{
    ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbConn"]
 });
```

And I'm passing the data where I need it go by passing into my classes constructor like so:

```
FileUpload files = new FileUpload(repo, outPutFolder);
```

Finally, I'm setting it in the required location in my target class as follows:

```
 private static DbRepository databaseConnectionString;

// how I'm using it
   var connectionString = databaseConnectionString;
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandText = sqlstring;
                loadContextId = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
```

To keep this brief, I've omitted the actual constructor on my FileUpload class. I've debugged my project and everything is getting pulled correction, but my project is failing when it gets to the `using` statement.

The error I get is:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 0.

A quick search on this told me that there is a problem with my connection format so I tested it by pasting the connection line directly into the method, and my project my ran fine. So I'm at a loss as to why this happening as my SQL connection looks to be correct.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: use this may sove your problem: `<add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=RoomViewr;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: Where you are assigning the value to databaseConnectionString?

Comment: use `Initial Catalog` instead of `Server`

Comment: Remove : "ToString()".  It is already a string and you are probably getting the object type.

Comment: @combo_ci do I need to put that in another section of the App.Config?

Comment: @combo_ci also I tried Initial catalog instead of server and same issue

Comment: yes a section like :`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=RoomViewr;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: @jdweng the ToString() is there for a reason. taking it away there is an error: cannot convert from 'Repository.DbRepository' to 'string'

Comment: There is an issue with :  var connectionString = databaseConnectionString;  It is not  a string and should be a string.  You need to find out what the actual type is and only get the string portion and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're reading the DbRepository object itself (databaseConnectionString) into your connectionString variable, not a ConnectionString property. So unless you've overridden DbRepository.ToString() to return the connection string, you're not getting your connection string back but just the object type.

Comment: Yes exactly, databaseConnectionString is object... Please put your break point in databaseConnectionString.

Comment: So what would be the best way to return the connection string? I've been trying for a while and I'm stumped. Using App.Config is something new to me. As well as passing it down the line like I'm doing

Comment: You're actually already reading the connection string as part of this: static DbRepository repo = new DbRepository(new DbRepositoryConfig
{
    ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbConn"]
 });

Comment: But you're not using repo again anywhere, and it's not clear what the connection between DbRepository and DbRepositoryConfig is, or your target class

Answer (score 0):

Create your BaseRepository like this.

```
  public class BaseRepository 
  {
     public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }

     static BaseRepository ()
     {
            ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbConn"];
     }
  }
```

And your repository class should be like this.

```
public class YourRepostiory : BaseRepository 
{
    public void YourMethod()
    {
        var connectionString = base.ConnectionString;

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandText = sqlstring;
                loadContextId = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!!